# Map Makar Input text data

Tags: android

I'm developing an android map that accept inputs from the marker. When the user taps on the marker, there's a alertDialog that receives input. How can I get the data from the Alert Dialog. I want to upload a picture but I can't cause I need 10points to do so. Thank You.

```
maps.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);            
        LayoutInflater infs = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        alert.setView(infs.inflate(R.layout.info_window, null)).setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                    
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alerts = alert.create();                    
        alerts.show();
    }
});
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please post your code so we can understand what you actually want to do and pls tell me what kind of data you want to get from alert Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

In ***AlertDialog*** you can set ***positive*** and ***negative*** button like ***OK*** and ***Cancel***.

Pressing on OK button you can get the data from it.

For ex, If there is EditText in ***AlertDialog*** then you can get value of EditText on click of ***OK*** button something like:

```
String value = yourEdittext.getText().toString():
```

And call ***dialog.dismiss()*** for dismiss the dialog on click on ***Cancel*** button.

***EDIT:***

```
maps.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);            
    LayoutInflater infs = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = infs.inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
    ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourlistView);
    alert.setView(v);
    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                    
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alerts = alert.create();                    
    alerts.show();
}
});
```

Comment: Okay, I just remember what I wanted to do. I wanted to use a listview in the dialog. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.For that you have to make custom layout in which your ListView will be and inflate that view.

Comment: Yeah, look at the code. I use an Inflater and den call the Layout, which is working....but, I want to test the ListView if it's working, but couldn't get it to work. Please, i wouldn't mind your email...maybe I can send you the whole code...Thanks

Comment: So in that layout is there a ListView?

Comment: yeah, there is a ListView

Comment: what I did was, I created an edittext, a ListView and a Button to test it, when text is entered into the editText and the button is clicked it should populate the ListView.

Comment: All three widgets are in your info_window.xml and want to open all this in AlertDialog??

Comment: Yes..you can. For that what you have do, after entered value in editText and press OK button you have to hide both button and edittext and show ListView and populated data in that which entered in edittext

Answer (score 0):

In `AlertDialog` you set a `Button` "OK" and  `setOnClickListener`
for this button. In the `onClickListener` you get the input from other controls and call `dialog.dismiss()` so the dialog closes.